# Script execution to continue even if redirection to a file fails

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

Its a  typical scenario that, we redirect script outputs to a file. 
Either because of a permissions issue or whatsoever reason, output file cant be created. (Typically, these are log files implemented as NFR requirement of the product)
Now, because of this, script execution itself is being blocked. 
Is there a way that, this scenario can be avoided that, script execution should still continue if the output file cant be created.

Comment: What´s wrong with a simple: *touch $FILENAME: $? && echo it works || echo it works not* ?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the data in the case it can not be written to the designated file?

Comment: Or, putting it another way: When the redirection fails, or would fail, how would you know, in the general case, that the continued operation of the script would be safe?

Comment: Log file writing is a non-functional requirement. As an output of the script, I'm redirecting it a file. And unfortunately, this file couldnt be created. But, I dont want my script execution to fail if this output file creation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the redirection is processed before the associated command is executed, if the redirection fails, the command won't be executed at all.

So, for

```bsh
./script.sh >"$output"
```

to successfully run the script even though the redirection to the file in `$output` fails, we would first have to detect whether it would be possible to do the redirection, manually.

This may be tested by redirecting the output from e.g. `echo` and catching whether it fails or not:

```bsh
if ! echo >"$output" 2>/dev/null; then
    output=/dev/null
fi

./script.sh >"$output"
```

Here, we redirect the output to `/dev/null` if the default output file is not usable.  You may instead use e.g. `/dev/stdout` in place of `/dev/null` if you instead of discarding the output want it to go to standard output.

Comment: btw, testing with `touch` would give a false positive if the file exists and is owned by the same user. `touch` uses `utimensat()`, which says [you need either to be the owner, or to have write access](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/utimensat.html) (or superuser privilege). This prints an error for the second redirection on Mac and Linux at least: `rm -f test.txt; echo foo > test.txt; chmod a-w test.txt; touch test.txt && echo bar > test.txt && echo ok`

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes. I honestly don't see what I was on about in that answer.  Testing with `echo` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to use the logging subsystem that already exists (`syslog`). The command-line tool to access this is `logger`.

Set the facility `user` with an appropriate priority of output (errors, warnings, information, debugging, etc.) and the tag to a label that represents your program and you're done:

```
your_program 2>&1 | logger -t your_program -p user.info
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tee` as a middleman instead of directly redirecting the output of the command. It will not stop just because of a failure in opening an output file.

```
$ cat out.sh
#!/bin/bash
outfile=${1-/dev/null}
echo hello | tee "$outfile"
echo done.
$ touch unwritable; chmod a-w unwritable
$ bash out.sh unwritable 
tee: unwritable: Permission denied
hello
done.
```

The exit status of the pipeline will be the exit status of the last command, `tee`. If you need the exit status of the first part of the pipeline, you can use e.g. Bash's `PIPESTATUS` array to get it.

Redirect the output of `tee` to `/dev/null` if you don't want a copy of the output to the script's standard output.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have to inspect how to integrate this with the general architecture for scripts.